# sailsjs dynamic routing for all controllers

Tags: node.js, dynamic, yii, routes, sails.js

I am new in **sailsjs** faced with the problem of routing
I have in mind when my address in my application to the following for all control of my creation:

```
'r|^/events/(\\d+)$|id': "eventsController.view",
'r|^/notifications/(\\d+)$|id': "notificationsController.view"
```

I worked in the past in the **framework Yii** in php using regular expressions can return the following routing:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/' => '<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/' => '<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

I want yii routing system in my Implementation sailsjs

Comment: you probably should look at this: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api?q=blueprint-routes

Comment: I read every documentations in sails website but not useful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the patterns you've specified, you needn't write a regex.

Assuming your URL has only two dynamic parts (the last two components), you could use something like this:

`'/:param1/:param2': 'MyController.action'`

which will accept both the URLs you've provided and allow access to "notifications"/"events" as `req.param('param1')` and the id as `req.param('param2')`.

To keep the second parameter optional, you could use:
`'/:param1/:param2?': 'MyController.action'`

For the regex version, use:
`'r|^/(events|notifications)/(\\d+)$|page,id': 'MyController.action'`

**Edit**
For basic blueprint-like usage:
`'r|^/(\\w+)/(\\d*)/(\\w*)$|model,id,action': 'AuthController.action'`

(I've only considered page, id and action here; you can add other relevant params.)

Then, in your controller:

```
var model = req.param('model')
, id = req.param('id')
, action = req.param('action');
sails.models[model][action]({ id: id }).exec(callback);
```

You can modify this per your requirements. Note that you'll need to validate the inputs thoroughly (check if the models exist, the actions are valid and so on).

That said, you should seriously consider not going down this lane since blueprints do this for you already. (Even support plurals!) Consider abstracting common logic into a Service and calling it from individual controllers.

Comment: is useless for me because my controllers dynamic and i need create route for all controllers to show "view Action" in all controllers

Comment: @Morteza: Check out the edit. You could narrow it down to support just the `view` action that you require.